# Discrete metric space and continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, metric-spaces

May someone please tell me if the following proof is correct? Also, may someone please tell me what I could possibly do to improve the structure and proof in general?

What I want to prove: Let Let X and Y be metric spaces. Assume X is a discrete metric space. Then $f: E_{discrete} \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

My proof: Let p$\in E_{discrete}$. Let $\epsilon >0$. What I want to show is that $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta >0$ : $\forall x\in E$ if $x \in N_{\delta}(p)$ then $f(x) \in N_{\epsilon}(f(p))$. Set $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$ then for $x\in E_{discrete}$ if $d(x,p)<\delta$ then clearly $d(x,p)=0$ and so $d(f(x),f(p))=0 < \epsilon$. Is my proof correct? What can I do to improve it? I've heard that the result follows vacuously but i'm not sure why that is the case. Isn't a vacuous truth a truth for when a statement p is false and q in true in a statement p $\implies q$ ?

Comment: You are correct, both in your argument and your understanding of of "vacuous." An example of a vacuous truth would be that the empty set is open in a metric space - since openness since a statement about all members of a set, it is necessarily true about a set which has no members.

Comment: In order to improve your proof just few details: if you have $X$ and $Y$ don't use $E$. It is undefinided. Furthermore, once you say that the distance is the discrete, the subscript is unnecessary.

Comment: What is you definition of discrete metric space? Is it a metric space such that the induced topology is discrete? Or is it one where the metric takes only values 0 or 1 depending on whether $x=y$ or not? If $d$ is such a metric, the scaled metric $d'=(1/8)d$ also induces the discrete topology, but you cannot choose $\delta=1/2$ anymore.

Comment: my definition of a discrete metric space is a set with the discrete metric so it depends on values 0 or 1. Why can't I take 1/2 anymore? @ThibautDumont

Comment: With your definition of a discrete metric $d$, the proof works well. On the other hand, if you use the metric $d'$ defined by $d'(x,y)=\frac{1}{8}d(x,y)$, the proof doesn't work anymore.